# Teleport tsh login error - minimum client version supported by the server is 9.0.0

Tags: teleport

Getting error while trying to access **Teleport** via tsh login

```
error: minimum client version supported by the server is 9.0.0. Please upgrade the client, downgrade the server, or use the
--skip-version-check flag to by-pass this check.
```

Upgrading version doesn't help as it downloads the files but says no auth to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked after I cleared the tsh/kube teleport config

```
cat /dev/null >~/.kube/config  
rm -rf ~/.tsh 
rm -rf ~/.kube/teleport-*
```

and refreshed the VPN connection

Answer (score 1):

Few questions:

1. What client version are you running? Do a `tsh version`.
2. `v9` of Teleport is pretty old and getting near EOL (see https://goteleport.com/docs/faq/#supported-versions). So you might want to consider upgrading your cluster itself.

If you're on MacOS or Windows you can install the `tsh` binary with our installation packages. If you are getting errors it might be a local issue most likely.

Comment: Yes this seems to be a local config issue. Sorted out though. For the v9 teleport eol - yeah its an orgwide upgrade that is required for us. Until then we might have to fix the leakages and live with it

Comment: Glad you were able to sort it out. Also, feel free to join our community Slack channel. You'll typically get faster response there than SO most likely!